# How to publish a message to AWS Iot from ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have created a java app to publish an MQTT message using aws iot sdk. I am able to publish messages from my local environment however get the following error when deployed to ec2.
I have added a role(AWSIoTFullAccess) to the ec2 instance but still getting this error.
How can I make this app publish messages from ec2?

```
c.a.s.i.c.m.AwsIotMqttConnectionListener : Connect request failure

org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: MqttException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade.
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:162) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:80) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:65) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2.jar:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.mqtt.AwsIotMqttConnectionListener.onFailure Connect request failure
    MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade.
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade.
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
        ... 1 more
```

Error when tried to downgrade Iot SDK and Paho version to 1.1.0:

```
c.a.s.i.c.m.AwsIotMqttConnectionListener : Connect request failure

org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: MqttException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:664) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:133) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:74) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:77) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:650) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.0.jar:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.mqtt.AwsIotMqttConnectionListener.onFailure Connect request failure
    MqttException (0) - java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:664)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:650)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: The error isn't related to credentials -- it seems to be saying that it can't reach AWS. What are the Outbound rules on the Security Group attached to the instance? If you ssh into the instance, can you run an AWS CLI command like `aws s3 ls`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have not set any outbound rules. It is allowing all traffic type (IP4, 0.0.0.0/0). I have also tried allowing all traffic type to inbound rules but still getting the same error.
Yes, I was able to run "aws s3 ls" and got a list of s3 buckets.

Comment: Might be related to `paho` client, see: [IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade · Issue #479 · aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android · GitHub](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/479)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried downgrading the version of IoT SDK and Paho to 1.1.0 but still getting an error (editted the description to include error message)